# my code has an error when i try to remove a document from a collection in mongodb by java

Tags: java, mongodb, jsp

i can get a true id by click on remove button in previous jsp file

```
try{

    MongoClient client = new MongoClient("localhost",27017);
    DB db = client.getDB("crawler");
    DBCollection collection=db.getCollection("enduser");

    DBObject doc=new BasicDBObject();

    DBCursor curs = collection.find();

    String value = request.getParameter("_id");     

    collection.remove((DBObject)doc.put("_id",value));

    System.out.println(value+"");       

}catch(UnknownHostException e){

    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Not sure what your issue is. You haven't shown any error, or any output. What *should* be happening? What *is* happening? Please edit your question accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

`value` needs to be an `ObjectId`, not a `String`.  Try this:

```java
collection.remove((DBObject)doc.put("_id", new ObjectId(value)));
```

Comment: ObjectId(value) => give me error ObjectId cannot be resolved to a type

Comment: You need to import `org.bson.types.ObjectId`.  See http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.5/bson/installation-guide/

Comment: type Exception report

message An exception occurred processing JSP page /delete.jsp at line 34

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception 
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /delete.jsp at line 34

31:   
32:  String value = request.getParameter("_id");
33:  
34:  collection.remove((DBObject)doc.put("_id", new ObjectId()));
  




after adding the import give me that error @Paul

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException
 com.mongodb.OutMessage.writeRemove(OutMessage.java:182)
 com.mongodb.OutMessage.remove(OutMessage.java:69)
 com.mongodb.DBApiLayer$MyCollection.remove(DBApiLayer.java:287)
 com.mongodb.DBCollection.remove(DBCollection.java:250)

Comment: why nullpointerException although i can get the select "_id" ??

Comment: You need `new ObjectId(value)`, not `new ObjectId()`.

Comment: thanks a lot @paul it worked well what about if i need to edit my documents ?

Comment: You'll need to do an `update` to update one or more documents.  See http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.5/driver/tutorials/perform-write-operations/#update-existing-documents